# Apache Phoenix Upsert not working while trying to update null/empty columns

Tags: null, hadoop

Step 1: Update a column with null value.

```
Upsert into abc.tablename (Rowkeycombo1, Rowkeycombo2, columnname) values (123,to_date('1988-08-06'),null);
```

This works fine and the column then appears to have no data while doing a select.

Step 2:Update the same column with a valid value.

```
Upsert into abc.tablename (Rowkeycombo1, Rowkeycombo2, columnname) values (123,to_date('1988-08-06'),'TRYVAL');
```

Shows 1 row affected but the column still appears null/empty.

However there is no issue while updating a column which has a valid value to any other value.

I'm using a Phoenix server to query an Hbase DB and I'm new to both of this.